# multiple regression compare with and without outlier case

Tags: r, regression, outliers

I am currently conducting a multiple regression and have identified 3 major outliers within the data using the `aq.plot` function in the `mvoutlier` package. One case in particular seems highly unlikely and I am trying to find a way to compare my model with and without this one case. Is there a function to do this?

Comment: You can save the indexes of the outliers produced from `aq.plot` like: `outliers <- which(aq.plot(z, alpha=0.1)$outliers)`, which you can then use to remove the outlier cases.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to remove just one?

Comment: The `aq.plot` should show the number/index for the most extreme case. Then you can just do `dataset[-outliernumber,]`